# How to prevent some value (or state) from being shared across threads?

Tags: haskell

Say, I'm writing a library which exposes a `ReaderT` monad that looks like...

```hs
data LibEnv = LibEnv { envThreadUnsafeResource :: _whatever }

type LibraryT = ReaderT LibEnv
```

How do I prevent the user's of my library from calling `forkIO` from within a `MonadIO m => LibraryT m` monad without re-initialising `envThreadUnsafeResource`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping `_whatever` into a `Pool _whatever` from the `resource-pool` library which is usually used for managing database connections etc.

To construct a `Pool _whatever`, you will need to provide a `IO _whatever` for resource construction and a `_whatever -> IO ()` for resource destruction. If you then access `_whatever` by using only using the `withResource` function, then you can get a freshly initialised `_whatever` regardless of what threading context you are in.